# Когда лучше используется явный Intent , а когда неявный?

Tags: android

Изучаю android, и не могу понять, явный Intent используется, когда вызывается Activity только данного приложения, а неявный Intent, когда я хочу вызвать Activity не только из данного приложения, но и из другого, которое находится в системе?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Явные объекты Intent указывают компонент, который требуется запустить,
>   по имени ( полное имя класса). Явные объекты Intent обычно
>   используются для запуска компонента из вашего собственного приложения,
>   поскольку вам известно имя класса операции или службы, которую
>   необходимо запустить. Например , можно запустить новую операцию в
>   ответ на действие пользователя или запустить службу, чтобы загрузить
>   файл в фоновом режиме.
>
> Неявные объекты Intent не содержат имени конкретного компонента.
>   Вместо этого они в целом объявляют действие, которое требуется
>   выполнить, что дает возможность компоненту из другого приложения
>   обработать этот запрос. Например, если требуется показать пользователю
>   место на карте, то с помощью неявного объекта Intent можно запросить,
>   чтобы это сделало другое приложение, в котором такая возможность
>   предусмотрена.

В документации на самом деле все очень подробно описано.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=ru